# Immutable smart contract

Tags: smart-contract, tokens, best-practices

In EOS, smart contracts can be updated by the account owner.

This could be a problem for certain applications in finance. For instance, if I want to deploy a token, the transfer function should be non-updatable. And in general, I want, as a developer, that the entire smart contract cannot be updated to guarantee reliability. So, users have to trust the smart contract only and not also the developer, hoping that updates are not malicious.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can..

**Create a token on an existing token contract where it's administered by a trusted party.**

Or,

**Create your own token contract then remove the keys from the account, therefore making it possible to update.**

Comment: It's difficult to find a trusted party… I think it's the same of administrating the account by yourself. And if I'm not wrong, the second option is like doing nothing since if I have the control of my account I can also add the keys again.

Comment: No, if you remove the keys that's it, you can't add the keys back again.